# Cannot segue from UILabel to ViewController

Tags: ios, uilabel, segue, uistoryboardsegue

in the storyboard, I am trying to segue from a label to a view controller. For whatever reason, it's not going. Has anyone else experience this?

Comment: You would need to add a UIGestureRecognizer to the label programatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not possible. You can only segue from UIControls or subclasses of it, like UIButtons.

UILabels don't have target-action methods for activating the segue. An alternative is to use UITapGestureRecognizer on the label and run the segue yourself.

But simply using a button is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Style the UIButton to appear like a Label and then perform your navigation, just a quick hack.